# How do I convert raw camera data into a Bitmap on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, raw-data, format-conversion

I obtain raw camera data `rawData` of type `byte[]`, format RGBA, size 640x480, 4 bytes per pixel, from a library function. And I need to convert it to a Bitmap and display in an ImageView on the screen.

What I do is the following:

```
byte[] JPEGData = convertToJpeg(rawData, 640, 480, 80);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(JPEGData , 0, JPEGData .length);    
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

where `convertToJpeg()` function is:

```
    public static byte[] convertToJpeg(byte[] buffer, int w, int h, int quality) {
        YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(buffer, ImageFormat.NV21, w, h, null);

        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, quality, output_stream);

        Bitmap sourceBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(output_stream.toByteArray(), 0, output_stream.size());
        Bitmap destBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBmp, (int) (w * 0.75), (int) (h * 0.75), true);

        ByteArrayOutputStream pictureStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        destBmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, pictureStream);
        byte[] pictureByteArray = pictureStream.toByteArray();

        return pictureByteArray;
    }
```

After `decodeByteArray()` call I have `bitmap.getConfig() == ARGB_8888`.

However, what I see on the screen is some chaotic picture, with some blurry green shapes of what's been in the original picture.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Nobosy knows any solution ?

Comment: It seems blurry simply because the content of the Bitmap is encoded (NV21 format I think). So if you try to view it as a png or jpg file, it won't work. You first need to decode it before saving it.

Comment: @Simon, Didn't understand you. Bitmap is further displayed in an ImageView as follows: `(imageView.setBitmap(bitmap));`. What should I do?

Comment: You must decode it before. Using this instruction on a ImageView, it will try to decode it as a regular ARGB bitmap. But, the byte[] is not in ARGB format. (maybe something like YUYV)

Comment: @Simon, I do: 1) `byte[] JPEGData = convertToJpeg(rawData, ...);` where `convertToJpeg` is listed above. And 2) `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(JPEGData , 0, JPEGData .length);` Do I have to decode data, as you say, at step 1 or after step 3?

Comment: You should do it at the begining. In your example `byte[] buffer` should be converted to ARGB format. I think that `compressToJpeg` is expecting to have a ARGB format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60076/discussion-between-alexander-shmuratko-and-simon-marquis).

Comment: @Simon, I've just checked `rawData` format - its `RGBA`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution has turned out to be simple. And no need to convert to JPEG.

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(rawData));
```

Comment: I just try your code. But I am getting error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels" @Alexander Shmuratko

Comment: @JigarShekh Please check if your width and height are correct. :)

Comment: @Sipty Wondering where you can find the height and width?

Comment: If you have access to the camera settings, you can take the capture resolution from the setup directly. Or you can try getting it from the ImageReader, if you're using one as the output for the camera data.

Answer (score 0):

ByteBuffer().rewind to reset the buffer position to 0 than the "buffer not large enough for pixels" solved